# how to host a website with subdomains that use different technologies?

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, hosting, web-hosting

I want to host an asp.net core e-commerce website alongside a wordpress based blog.
being that the technologies a different how can I host them under the same domain name on the same server?
I'd like to have the result look something like this.
shop.domainname.com
blog.domainname.com

Comment: If using IIS, you can set the host name under each site.

Comment: Word press can be installed inside IIS - refer - https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS . And then you need to configure the dns entry to point to the same web server for all the site.  As @MarkG G suggested above use host names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a proxy server like nginx.
here is minimalistic configuration for nginx.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  shop.domainname.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  blog.domainname.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
        }
    }
}
```

other useful documentations [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/)